Append associatve elements to each row while looping a mysqli query result
I am using the following code to generate additional data for each row of my query result set.
while ($row = $table->fetch_array()) {
    $formula = [
        'tkoSum' => $this->getTkoSum($row['id']),
        'chko' => $this->getChko($row['id'])
    ];
    $containers[] = ['info' => $row, 'formula' => $formula];
}

My current result ($containers) is:
[
    0 => [
        'info' => ['id' => 1, 'category' => 'МКД'],
        'formula' => ['tkoSum' => '12', 'chko' => '15']
    ],
    1 => [
        'info' => ['id' => 2, 'category' => 'Офис'],
        'formula' => ['tkoSum' => '62', 'chko' => '45']
    ]
]

But I need a 2d structure with indexed rows containing associative elements like this:
[
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'category' => 'МКД',
        'tkoSum' => '12',
        'chko' => '15'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'category' => 'Офис',
        'tkoSum' => '62',
        'chko' => '45'
    ]
];

How can this be achieved?

Append the additional data using the union operator.
while ($row = $table->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $containers[] = $row
    + [
        'tkoSum' => $this->getTkoSum($row['id']),
        'chko' => $this->getChko($row['id'])
    ];
}


Assuming this is a natuve mysqli API call, then I would expect to see fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) to ensure that indexed keys are not also included in the row payloads.  I also recommend foreach() instead of while() to iterate the result set object.

this while works, but what will be the advantage of foreach?

foreach() removes the need to call ->fetch_array().  However, I changed by script back to while() so that the script can merely append the associative elements to a fully associative row without the excess indexed elements pointing to redundant values.

Well, assuming the category value comes from the associative array in $row, would the following work?
    while ($row = $table->fetch_array()) {
    $containers[] = [$row['id'], $row['category'], $this->getTkoSum($row['id']), $this->getChko($row['id'])];
}


This would work, but the table I get from the database contains a lot of values that can also be added in the process, and if the query looks like this, the newly added values will not be displayed

This answer also does not include any column names in the populated rows.

This answer does not provide the required result.

you can do this;
$newContainers = [];

foreach ($containers as $key => $container) {
    $newContainers[$key] = [
        'id' => $container['info']['id'],
        'category' => $container['info']['category'],
        'tkoSum' => $container['formula']['tkoSum'],
        'chko' => $container['formula']['chko']
    ];
}

print_r($newContainers);

or if you want keys to be not hardcoded;
$newContainers = [];

foreach ($containers as $key => $container) {
    $newContainer = [];
    foreach ($container as $subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $subKey => $subValue) {
            $newContainer[$subKey] = $subValue;
        }
    }
    $newContainers[$key] = $newContainer;
}

print_r($newContainers);


"Do this" or "do this" isn't much of an explanation. Working from $containers means two loops -- which is unnecessary extra work because only one loop is required.

What about this?
while ($row = $table->fetch_array()) {
    $vals_arr = array();

    foreach($row as $next_val) {
        $vals_arr[] = $next_val;
    }

    $containers[] = [implode(', ', $next_val), $this->getTkoSum($row['id']), $this->getChko($row['id'])];
}


You forgot to explain your code.

The question never asked to implode anything.
